# Sending SMS to Arduino

Tags: arduino, at-command, arduino-esp8266, wifimanager

Can I assign a text message sent from my gsm module to a variable in Arduino code?

I have tried to work on sending SMS to gsm module from my mobile phone. I want to write a code to send sms to GSM module and assign the variable to a defined variable in Arduino code. For example sending sms to assign password and ssid for WiFi Manager.

Comment: What is your gsm module? you need to read its inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Read more about how to use GSM with [Arduino here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield).